# Fill lines on a dataset

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm working with a dataset that is like this:

```
df3
```

```
    id  Carats  Cert    Clarity Color   Cut Depth   Fluroescence    Known_Conflict_Diamond  Measurements    Polish  Regions Shape   Symmetry    Table   Vendor  Offers  Price   Retail  Possible_profit
0   8051    0.42    AGSL    SI2 L       62.7    None    NaN 4.81x4.78x3.01  Excellent   Australia   Round   Excellent   57.0    1   NaN 861.5   1315.233051 453.733051
1   8052    0.40    GemEx   VS2 M       63.8    None    NaN 4.64x4.61x2.95  Excellent   Australia   Round   Excellent   59.0    1   NaN 901.5   1315.233051 413.733051
2   8053    0.41    AGSL    SI2 L       62.2    None    True    4.76x4.74x2.95  Excellent   DR Congo    Round   Very good   58.0    1   NaN 911.0   1315.233051 404.233051
3   8054    0.40    AGSL    SI1 K       64.2    Strong Bl.. False   4.63x4.59x2.96  Very good   Angola  Emerald Very good   58.0    1   NaN 901.5   1315.233051 413.733051
4   8055    0.40    AGSL    VS2 L       64.3    NaN False   4.67x4.62x2.99  Excellent   Russia  Round   Very good   NaN 1   NaN 901.5   1315.233051 413.733051
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
2678    10729   1.65    AGSL    VS1 E   Excellent   58.4    None    NaN 7.79x7.83x4.56  Excellent   Canada  Pear    Excellent   60.0    4   NaN 14574.0 21546.730769    6972.730769
2679    10730   2.35    AGSL    SI2 E   Excellent   62.1    None    True    8.48x8.53x5.28  Excellent   Angola  Round   Excellent   58.0    2   NaN 35708.5 52026.764706    16318.264706
2680    10731   2.35    AGSL    SI2 J   Excellent   NaN None    NaN 8.64x8.67x5.2   Excellent   Russia  Pear    Very good   NaN 2   NaN 35708.5 52026.764706    16318.264706
2681    10732   5.02    AGSL    I1  J   Excellent   59.5    None    NaN 11.16x11.18*6.64    Excellent   Russia  Oval    Excellent   59.0    2   NaN 163276.5    250882.500000   87606.000000
2682    10733   1.00    AGSL    SI2 E   Very good   59.7    NaN NaN 6.42x6.45x3.84  Excellent   Russia  Round   Excellent   61.0    2   NaN 7369.5  11785.729730    4416.229730
2683 rows × 20 columns
```

I want to fill the lines 26, 426 and 264 of the column 'Offers' with the values of the 'Price' column of these lines. How can I make it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `loc` to only alter the rows with the specific `index` you want with the columns you want:

```
r = [26,426,264]
df3.loc[r,'Offers'] = df3.loc[r,'Price']
```